# rendering multiple images in a browser in a video like fashion

Tags: javascript, html

I have approximatively 500 images that differ very slightly one from another. They are all of the same size. They hence form a sort of video when watched one after the other very fast.

I am looking for a way to display them in a browser (html file from disk), all in the same spot, to form that video looking effect. I want to be able to play, pause, stop, play faster, play slower (and if possible even more controls, such as maybe go to specific time (ie, image 47, if there's a slider for example; if there's only play,pause,fast and slow it's okay though).

I am not a programmer but I think javascript might do that. If there's a better technology, please redirect me to it. I'm just looking for a solution that works the way I intend, but I have no javascript knowledge. This surely has been done before though, so I would gladly accept a working solution.

Comment: Convert to video, upload to youtube, embed youtube url ;)

Comment: You could use some gif convertors which would convert those images to a single gif and optimize those images too.

Comment: I agree with @rsplak - convert to video.  Otherwise, you could use the canvas element, and load the images into the canvas.  Javascript would drive the animation, and you could build the controls that you need.  Since you are NOT a programmer, save yourself some trouble, and convert to video...

Comment: rsplak that's a solution, but the images are changing often and I don't want to upload to youtube everytime (and I don't want my personal work to be publicly accessible, not to mention the youtube user agreement). yogi I know very little about gifs, but I don't think you can stop or pause them or change the speed on the fly.

Comment: The problem with trying to emulate video using still frames and Javascript is that the performance will be terrible. Video codecs are refined, optimised and continually improved. You'd lose all those benefits, and incur a huge CPU hit, as I can't see a way to hardware-accelerate this in the browser.

Comment: @CMKanode so, if I am to convert to video, can you please tell me 1. what tool to use (preferably lightweight command line linux free tool) and how, and more importantly, 2. how to embed a video in a html page, so that it's playable by a plugin such as totem or vlc or something like that

Comment: @ChrisFrancis ok, let's go for a video. Please see the question I addressed to CMKanode above.

Comment: The concept of advancing through a set of images in some viewer element without the complexity and time waste of making a video is applicable to enough other applications/scenarios, like surveillance, to make this question a very good one.  Especially considering the answer that it inspired.  I could not bear to see it rated at -1 so I upvoted it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although you seem to be going the conversion route, here is a solution that uses javascript, allows pausing, jump to frame, and changing speed (I didn't bother with a slider for this [or a nice UI for any of it]):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body onload="launch()">
</body>
<script>
var frames=['frame1.png','frame2.png','frame3.png','frame4.png','frame5.png','frame6.png','frame7.png','frame8.png','frame9.png','frame10.png'];
var playing=true;
var on_frame=0;
var timer;

function launch(){
    document.body.innerHTML='<img id="film" src="frames/'+frames[on_frame]+'"/><br/><button id="actionbutton">Play</button><button onclick="stop()">Stop</button><br/>Milliseconds between frames:<input type="text" id="framerate" value="50"/><br/>Go to frame:<input type="text" id="gotoframe"><button onclick="goFrame(document.getElementById(\'gotoframe\').value);">Go</button>';   
    document.getElementById('actionbutton').addEventListener('click',play); 
    play();
}

function change(){
    document.getElementById('film').src='frames/'+frames[on_frame]; //I have my images in a folder named frames
    on_frame++;
    if(on_frame==frames.length){on_frame=0;}
    if(playing){
        timer=setTimeout(change,document.getElementById('framerate').value?document.getElementById('framerate').value:50);
    }
}

function play(){
    document.getElementById('actionbutton').removeEventListener('click',play);
    document.getElementById('actionbutton').addEventListener('click',pause);
    document.getElementById('actionbutton').innerHTML='Pause';
    clearInterval(timer);
    playing=true;
    change();
}

function pause(){
    document.getElementById('actionbutton').removeEventListener('click',pause);
    document.getElementById('actionbutton').addEventListener('click',play);
    document.getElementById('actionbutton').innerHTML='Play'; 
    playing=false; 

}

function stop(){
    document.getElementById('actionbutton').removeEventListener('click',pause);
    document.getElementById('actionbutton').addEventListener('click',play);
    document.getElementById('actionbutton').innerHTML='Play'; 
    playing=false; 
    on_frame=0;
}

function goFrame(x){
    if((x>-1)&&(x<=frames.length)){
        on_frame=x;
        if(!playing){document.getElementById('film').src='frames/'+frames[on_frame];}
    }
    else{
        alert('Out of range');
    }
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: That's great! Thank you very much. It works great, since I don't need to refresh that often, 1 image per second is enough. I saw where to modify that. I have a few enhancements, maybe you can help me with: initiate the page with the video starting, rather than not. Have the play button and pause button as the same button, and add a stop button. Most importantly, leave the default size of the image rather than imposing my own. Finally, having a slider for 'go to frame'. Once again, thanks

Comment: I made it autostart (and autosize), changed the play to a toggle...I'm not sure how you're distinguishing between pause and stop, so right now they're the same. For a slider you'll have to look at jQuery UI, or http://webhole.net/2010/04/24/html-5-slider-input-tutorial/ if you are sure your target user has support for that

Comment: Thanks. It's just for my own use, and I'm using the latest Firefox. If I'm at frame f=7, and I click pause, then 'play' should start at frame 7. Similarly, if I click stop, then the subsequent 'start' should start at frame 0, just like it would in a video/music file application.

Comment: done. You should look at the code, the differences between `pause` and `stop` and how the `change` function works, there's nothing particularly tricky, so it could be a good place to start learning JS